# Firebase Analytics on Android TV

Tags: firebase, analytics, android-tv, firebase-analytics

Does the [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) work on Android TV? I think it requires Google Play Services but they are not available for Android TV. If not, any suggested alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although Firebase does only officially support devices with Google Play services, some features (such as Analytics) may actually work on devices that do not have Google Play Services.  However, we cannot guarantee this.

Steve Ganem
Product Manager, Firebase Analytics

Comment: I have tried it with my Android TV app and i confirm that it works!

Comment: I have tried  with Android TV, and Fire-TV  its working.

Comment: its working, i have tested in android tv supported play service devices